# How to resolve 'Error: You need to provide a target platform' when trying to setup Webpack

Tags: webpack, nativescript

I am new to mobile app development and am trying to setup Webpack in my current mobile app. I am following the steps from Nativescript's website. After the initial installation, I am receiving 1 warning and 2 errors as seen here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJhg8.jpg

I am having a difficult time understanding why my modules are not found. I am thinking that I need to edit my webpack.config.js file but have been unsuccessful so far.

After reading posts online (and of course, webpack --help) I found this command: 
"$ webpack --display-error-details"
and was given some additional information seen here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxjOs.jpg

The error-details are telling me to provide a target platform. I have tried adding items from the list under the error to the appComponents array with no luck as well as other places in the webpack.config.js file.

My current webpack.config.js file:

```
const { join, relative, resolve, sep } = require("path");

const webpack = require("webpack");
const nsWebpack = require("nativescript-dev-webpack");
const nativescriptTarget = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/nativescript-target");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer");
const { NativeScriptWorkerPlugin } = require("nativescript-worker-loader/NativeScriptWorkerPlugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const hashSalt = Date.now().toString();

module.exports = env => {
    // Add your custom Activities, Services and other Android app components here.
    const appComponents = [
        "tns-core-modules/ui/frame",
        "tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity",
    ];

    const platform = env && (env.android && "android" || env.ios && "ios");
    if (!platform) {
        throw new Error("You need to provide a target platform!");
    }

    const platforms = ["ios", "android"];
    const projectRoot = __dirname;

    // Default destination inside platforms/<platform>/...
    const dist = resolve(projectRoot, nsWebpack.getAppPath(platform, projectRoot));
    const appResourcesPlatformDir = platform === "android" ? "Android" : "iOS";

    const {
        // The 'appPath' and 'appResourcesPath' values are fetched from
        // the nsconfig.json configuration file
        // when bundling with `tns run android|ios --bundle`.
        appPath = "app",
        appResourcesPath = "app/App_Resources",

        // You can provide the following flags when running 'tns run android|ios'
        snapshot, // --env.snapshot
        uglify, // --env.uglify
        report, // --env.report
        sourceMap, // --env.sourceMap
        hiddenSourceMap, // --env.hiddenSourceMap
        hmr, // --env.hmr,
        unitTesting, // --env.unitTesting
    } = env;
    const isAnySourceMapEnabled = !!sourceMap || !!hiddenSourceMap;
    const externals = nsWebpack.getConvertedExternals(env.externals);

    const appFullPath = resolve(projectRoot, appPath);
    const appResourcesFullPath = resolve(projectRoot, appResourcesPath);

    const entryModule = nsWebpack.getEntryModule(appFullPath, platform);
    const entryPath = `.${sep}${entryModule}.ts`;
    const entries = { bundle: entryPath };

    const tsConfigPath = resolve(projectRoot, "tsconfig.tns.json");

    if (platform === "ios") {
        entries["tns_modules/tns-core-modules/inspector_modules"] = "inspector_modules.js";
    };

    let sourceMapFilename = nsWebpack.getSourceMapFilename(hiddenSourceMap, __dirname, dist);

    const config = {
        mode: uglify ? "production" : "development",
        context: appFullPath,
        externals,
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: [
                appResourcesFullPath,
                // Don't watch hidden files
                "**/.*",
            ]
        },
        target: nativescriptTarget,
        entry: entries,
        output: {
            pathinfo: false,
            path: dist,
            sourceMapFilename,
            libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
            filename: "[name].js",
            globalObject: "global",
            hashSalt
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".scss", ".css"],
            // Resolve {N} system modules from tns-core-modules
            modules: [
                resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/tns-core-modules"),
                resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
                "node_modules/tns-core-modules",
                "node_modules",
            ],
            alias: {
                '~': appFullPath
            },
            // resolve symlinks to symlinked modules
            symlinks: true
        },
        resolveLoader: {
            // don't resolve symlinks to symlinked loaders
            symlinks: false
        },
        node: {
            // Disable node shims that conflict with NativeScript
            "http": false,
            "timers": false,
            "setImmediate": false,
            "fs": "empty",
            "__dirname": false,
        },
        devtool: hiddenSourceMap ? "hidden-source-map" : (sourceMap ? "inline-source-map" : "none"),
        optimization: {
            runtimeChunk: "single",
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    vendor: {
                        name: "vendor",
                        chunks: "all",
                        test: (module, chunks) => {
                            const moduleName = module.nameForCondition ? module.nameForCondition() : '';
                            return /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/.test(moduleName) ||
                                appComponents.some(comp => comp === moduleName);

                        },
                        enforce: true,
                    },
                }
            },
            minimize: !!uglify,
            minimizer: [
                new TerserPlugin({
                    parallel: true,
                    cache: true,
                    sourceMap: isAnySourceMapEnabled,
                    terserOptions: {
                        output: {
                            comments: false,
                            semicolons: !isAnySourceMapEnabled
                        },
                        compress: {
                            // The Android SBG has problems parsing the output
                            // when these options are enabled
                            'collapse_vars': platform !== "android",
                            sequences: platform !== "android",
                        }
                    }
                })
            ],
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: nsWebpack.getEntryPathRegExp(appFullPath, entryPath),
                    use: [
                        // Require all Android app components
                        platform === "android" && {
                            loader: "nativescript-dev-webpack/android-app-components-loader",
                            options: { modules: appComponents }
                        },

                        {
                            loader: "nativescript-dev-webpack/bundle-config-loader",
                            options: {
                                loadCss: !snapshot, // load the application css if in debug mode
                                unitTesting,
                                appFullPath,
                                projectRoot,
                            }
                        },
                    ].filter(loader => !!loader)
                },

                {
                    test: /-page\.ts$/,
                    use: "nativescript-dev-webpack/script-hot-loader"
                },

                {
                    test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
                    use: "nativescript-dev-webpack/style-hot-loader"
                },

                {
                    test: /\.(html|xml)$/,
                    use: "nativescript-dev-webpack/markup-hot-loader"
                },

                { test: /\.(html|xml)$/, use: "nativescript-dev-webpack/xml-namespace-loader" },

                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: { loader: "css-loader", options: { url: false } }
                },

                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        { loader: "css-loader", options: { url: false } },
                        "sass-loader"
                    ]
                },

                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "ts-loader",
                        options: {
                            configFile: tsConfigPath,
                            // https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/blob/ea2fcf925ec158d0a536d1e766adfec6567f5fb4/README.md#faster-builds
                            // https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/blob/ea2fcf925ec158d0a536d1e766adfec6567f5fb4/README.md#hot-module-replacement
                            transpileOnly: true,
                            allowTsInNodeModules: true,
                            compilerOptions: {
                                sourceMap: isAnySourceMapEnabled,
                                declaration: false
                            }
                        },
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            // Define useful constants like TNS_WEBPACK
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
                "process": undefined,
            }),
            // Remove all files from the out dir.
            new CleanWebpackPlugin([`${dist}/**/*`]),
            // Copy assets to out dir. Add your own globs as needed.
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.jpg" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.png" } },
            ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
            // Generate a bundle starter script and activate it in package.json
            new nsWebpack.GenerateBundleStarterPlugin(
                // Don't include `runtime.js` when creating a snapshot. The plugin
                // configures the WebPack runtime to be generated inside the snapshot
                // module and no `runtime.js` module exist.
                (snapshot ? [] : ["./runtime"])
                    .concat([
                        "./vendor",
                        "./bundle",
                    ])
            ),
            // For instructions on how to set up workers with webpack
            // check out https://github.com/nativescript/worker-loader
            new NativeScriptWorkerPlugin(),
            new nsWebpack.PlatformFSPlugin({
                platform,
                platforms,
            }),
            // Does IPC communication with the {N} CLI to notify events when running in watch mode.
            new nsWebpack.WatchStateLoggerPlugin(),
            // https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/blob/ea2fcf925ec158d0a536d1e766adfec6567f5fb4/README.md#faster-builds
            // https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/blob/ea2fcf925ec158d0a536d1e766adfec6567f5fb4/README.md#hot-module-replacement
            new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
                tsconfig: tsConfigPath,
                async: false,
                useTypescriptIncrementalApi: true,
                memoryLimit: 4096
            })
        ],
    };

    // Copy the native app resources to the out dir
    // only if doing a full build (tns run/build) and not previewing (tns preview)
    if (!externals || externals.length === 0) {
        config.plugins.push(new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {
                from: `${appResourcesFullPath}/${appResourcesPlatformDir}`,
                to: `${dist}/App_Resources/${appResourcesPlatformDir}`,
                context: projectRoot
            },
        ]));
    }

    if (report) {
        // Generate report files for bundles content
        config.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: "static",
            openAnalyzer: false,
            generateStatsFile: true,
            reportFilename: resolve(projectRoot, "report", `report.html`),
            statsFilename: resolve(projectRoot, "report", `stats.json`),
        }));
    }

    if (snapshot) {
        config.plugins.push(new nsWebpack.NativeScriptSnapshotPlugin({
            chunk: "vendor",
            requireModules: [
                "tns-core-modules/bundle-entry-points",
            ],
            projectRoot,
            webpackConfig: config,
        }));
    }

    if (hmr) {
        config.plugins.push(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
    }


    return config;
};
```

I have:
1. Updated all my dependencies
2. Modified the project successfully for short imports
3. Attempted to add these items under the error to my webpack.config file
4. Inspected the files from the warning/errors for clear signs of errors
5. Spent a lot of time online looking for potential solutions

I am still trying my best to figure out a solution and looking online for more information.

Comment: which version of {NS} are you using? Which platform are you testing this? What is the command that your are running?

Comment: The version of Nativescript is 5.4.0, I am testing on an android emulator, and the command I am using is { webpack --env.android } and { tns run android --bundle } which both produce the same 1 warning and 2 error messages as seen in my first image link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `webpack --env.ios` or `webpack --env.android` if you want to directly call the webpack compiler skipping the NativeScript CLI.

Regarding the errors, it seems that you have some invalid imports in `app.css` and `app-util.ts`. I suggest you start from a working sample application using `tns create`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I was previously using { tns run android --bundle } and it seems that { webpack --env.android } is producing the same results. Strangely enough, I do not have an app.css file which was part of the initial confusion. I do, however, have an app.ios.css, app.android.css, and app.common.css, as well as an app-util.ts file.

Comment: You are correct, Dimitar. Some of the imports in my app.ios.css, app.android.css, and app.common.css files were incorrect for Webpack. This is strange because there was no issue when it came to regular builds, without Webpack. I will continue investigating the imports. Thank you very much.